# Developing a programmed text similar to Quick Calculus: A Self-Teaching Guide

Tags: flashcards

I am interested in using LaTeX to put together a self-study guide (also called a programmed text). Quick Calculus: A Self-Teaching Guide is perhaps the most well known. Such books teach a topic through a series of panels. Each panel asks a question (usually with a yes/no answer) and the reader is directed and other panels depending on the answer. If the question is wrong, a destination panel explains the topic a bit more and may ask additional questions.  A correct answer moves the reader onto the next topic panel. I've looked at doing a homegrown effort in LaTeX and also looked at flashcards (also Mnemosyne) as a starting point but before commencing I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for packages that might already exist.

The main requirement is the ability to track panel identifiers (via labels), and render them on the panels with the appropriate labels for yes/no answers. Eg Three panels might have labels panel1, panel2, and panel3. A yes answer to the question on panel1 will point the reader to panel3 while a no answer will direct the reader to panel2. I haven't mentioned that answer panels also need to be provided either on the other side of the page or side by side with the question panel (or even in a separate document). The reader must obviously cover up the answer panels before answering a question.

Comment: I'm not aware of the existence of a LaTeX package that can do these things right out of the box, so to say. However, you should be able to get quite far by using the `hyperref` package and creating links from the correct-answer and incorrect-answer boxes to the next cells ("Panel3" and "Panel2" according to your description).